# What does "It's all you tab" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've just read a conversation on Facebook:

> Boy: You should be a model!
>
> Girl: **It's all you tab!**

What does she mean in the above context?

**Update**: I think i found [the right answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387566/what-does-its-all-you-tab-mean#comment913372_387566), thanks @Janus Bahs Jacquet

> That's all you **t**alk/**t**hink **ab**out

Comment: It’s impossible to tell.

Comment: No, I think Jim meant to say it's "impossible to know" what the message means without context, i.e. the background story.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=1794954&term=TAB scroll down, past the first definition

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  i'm so confused

Comment: Well how about giving the context? What were the two talking about? And if you don't understand, let me assure you that type of slang is not vitally important to know or learn. But my guess is that TAB is short for *Trendy Asian B**** h. Thanks goes to Urban Dictionary.

Comment: My guess (but it is absolutely nothing but a guess) is that it could mean “That's all you talk/think about”. I can think of no other meaning of _tab_ that would make any sense here.

Comment: first i thought she meant "it's up to your support" but on another photo, a friend of hers commented a smiley emoji and she replied the same phrase as above. BTW she's Australian, could this be Australian slang ?

Comment: POST what you think is the answer. @JanusBahsJacquet won't mind, in the slightest. Comments might get deleted, and the next poor sod who is left scratching their head when "tab" appears in their FB feed, won't know what the "answer" was. :) You can answer your questions, there's no rule against it. And you'll probably earn a few upvotes too.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA, i updated!  Your answer is good tho but Janus's is quite right on above context. 

Comment: I meant in the separate box...  an answer in the answer box... never mind.

Comment: hah, i'll do that next time.

Comment: Would the language used on FB be considered a dialect? Internet slang? Online slang?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is a reference to the:

> [tabby cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabby_cat)

which has an etymology linking it to clothes (Wikipedia):

> The English term tabby originates from the translation of the French phrase "striped silk taffeta", the root of which is tabis, meaning "a rich watered silk." This can be further traced to the Middle French atabis (14th century), which stemmed from the Arabic term attabiya. This word is a reference to the neighborhood in Baghdad, Attabiy (named for Prince Attab of the Umayyad Caliphate), where such silk cloth was first made. Tabby is also comparable to the Spanish word ataviar, which means "to decorate or to dress or wear" and often implies luxurious clothing.

Comment: What does a tabby cat have to do with being a model? I doubt that any modern person is aware of this etymology, or that they would use the word in the original sense.

Comment: With that scarcity of context in the original question, tabby cat is no worse answer than any other. At least it has an elaborate explanation. :-)